Why don't we shake lulav and esrog for Ana Hashem Hatzlicha Na?
On Sukkos, why do we shake Lulav and Esrog for Ana Hashem Hoshia Na and not for Ana Hashem Hatzlicha Na?

Note this is the position of Beit Hillel, but Beit Shammai says to wave during both and that used to be the popular practice (Mishna Sukka 3:9)

https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Berurah.651.38?lang=he

The Abudraham brings a few reasons.

We shake lulav to save us from evil spirits, so that only applies by hoshea na.
Cant shake twice on one pasuk. So we only shake by first part of pasuk hoshia na.

He also brings smach from pasuk to shake by hoshia na..

Re 2: Did Beit Shammai say to wave twice or to wave once spread over the whole verse?

@DoubleAA i assume twice.. the meleches shlomo and tos yom tov learn beis hillel with the smachta pshat. And tos yom tov explains the machlokes bh and bs. Acc to first answer its hard to explain why bs argues.

That's what people usually assume, I'm guessing because of how we read hallel today with them as two separate phrases, and how many wave with specific words mapped to specific directions. But it is really just one long verse. I wonder if there's any real proof. It may also depend how you understand הודו תחילה וסוף, if it means beginning and end of the pasuk then it fits for the same dispute to be here.

There is a nice pshat….
That for a yeshua one needs to look in all 4 corners of the world if it’s not here.
For hatzlacha we ask for us to merit it, but we don’t go somewhere else to all 4 corners of the world.
